# why Sql value change after updating data?

Tags: sql

I am running a site which is showing Alexa Ranking. The function to get Alexa Rank is working fine but when it insert the alexa rank from 1 to 10 to sql then why the value changes to 10, not 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

If the Alexa rank is 11+ then its showing fine, just not showing the Alexa ranking from 1 to 10.. its showing 10 instead.

What's the solution of it.?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you created any trigger ?

Comment: We need more information to help you with this. What statement are you using to update your data? What's your schema? Any triggers?

Comment: Show the code or nobody we'll be able to help!!!! :@

Comment: hi nidhin, what you mean by trigger. I didn't create anything, its a readymade script with this glitch.

Comment: Hello  Michael Petrotta, do you want to show the code when its adding or updating the values into mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Identity Seed is set to 10.

Comment: there's no column has IDENTITY value. Here's the table: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `worth` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alexa` int(12) NOT NULL,

Comment: Is it sql server? what's the database you are using ?

Comment: i tried to use another database which is showing the correct alexa rank, but when i run the script, its change the 1 to 10. so i think the problem is in script not in database but i don't know what variable uses for it and how to edit the script to insert the correct alexa rank in database.

Comment: Hi Charith, its a mysql database. It came with the script.

Comment: Its collecting the alexa rank correctly but when its inserting into mysql database, the value from 1 to 9 change to 10.. i think the php code has some problem.

Comment: This is mySql database. Please tell me how to sort out this problem. If you need the file, i can upload it here, or i can post the whole code but its very long.